# SSAS Cube Availability While Being Rebuilt

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas

Is a SSAS 2008 cube available to be queried while it's being rebuilt? If yes, then are there implications to querying it during a rebuild?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is, OLAP will keep a copy until the rebuild has finished. If your rebuild process requires a significantly long downtime then the only implications would be the load placedd on your SQL Server and the freshness of the data being returned by the old copy of your cube.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.  There are some features you can utilize to achieve this to varying degrees, but it is far from automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes, the cube can be queried while it's being processed. However:

- Right before the processing finishes, there's a window of up to `ForceCommitTimeout` ms (default **30 seconds**), during which [all new queries are queued while the in-flight queries are allowed to finish](https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2011/06/can-you-query-a-ssas-cube-while-it-is-processing/). This ensures the server will have a moment when no queries are executed and it can replace the cube's files with their new versions.
- You can [shoot yourself in the foot by processing the dimensions and the cube in different transactions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fe9342c3-d134-4049-993e-d15cff7c7a1c/cube-availability-during-processing?forum=sqlanalysisservices), in which case the cube will be unavailable for a longer time.
- Queries running in parallel with processing will (obviously) require more server resources. I've encountered query slowdowns as well as out-of-memory errors because of this.

https://support.jetglobal.com/hc/en-us/articles/218952048-High-Availability-Cube-Processing claims that **non-Enterprise editions** take the cube offline while processing, while selling something that is supposed to help fix it, but I'm unsure if that's in fact the case.